# Excel 365: nesting CELL in ADDRESS

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find a formula that will always automatically reference the cell to the left of any cell you put the formula in using A1 reference.  I've created this formula in Excel Office 365.

=ADDRESS(CELL("row"),CELL("col")-1,TRUE)

the problem with this formula is that it constantly recalculates the output depending on which cells I update.

For instance: if I put the above formula in E8, then the output should be $E$9.  However, the minute I type something underneath the cell in E10, the formula updates to $E$10.  If I put a value in F9, then the above formula updates to $F$9.

Anyone know why this is not working properly or how else to write this formula?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I realized that CELL is not the right function to use.  the formula should instead be:

=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)